# Using HTML elements while mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am currently fetching a data table and it has 2 values needs to be mapped. Mapping works just fine but I want to add some customisation to the text.

```
newDataRows(
dataToBeMapped.map((m) => ({
id: m.id, data:`<span>Bold Me:</span>${m.oldData}`
})));
```

I was hoping to have `<span>` portion to be worked but I get `[object Object]` on my browser. Is there any way to implement HTML in this line?

Comment: How are you *using* this HTML?  What you have is an object with two properties, one of which is a string.  You *may* want to use a JSX element instead of a string, but that depends on how you're using it.  What actually produces the incorrect output?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: m.oldData is probably an object. Use JSON.stringify to parse it to text or access a text property directly.

Comment: @Wimanicesir it is an object indeed. Mbistami 's answer below just resolved my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `data:'<span>Bold Me:</span>${m.oldData}'` with `data: <><span>Bold me</span>m.oldData</>`

And it's not HTML it is JSX
*[what's JSX?](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)*

Comment: the title is not projecting the issue correctly, that is my bad. Addition to your correction, thank you for the solution which works perfectly. I'll check the page you sent for sure.